# Save list of lists as rows in csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to save this in a csv file as follows:

```
index, name, lists

0, 'name1', [1, 2, 3]
1, 'name2', [4, 5, 6]
2, 'name3', [7, 8, 9]
```

If this is possible, then how should I do this with python?

Comment: Have you read through the python [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: @glibdud No I haven't read about the csv module but I tried writing to the file using python and the problem is that if I convert the sublists to a string, then the comma between them again acts as a separator and separates the sublist into more columns. I want the whole sublist to go in a single column

Comment: A comma separator value may be inappropriate in this case because to a parser, it's a bit ambiguous as what is a valid separator and what isn't when reading the file. A `\t` or tab-char may be more appropriate

Comment: I think the simplest would be to go and make a pandas dataframe and load your data in it and using to_csv function you can write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pandas to assemble your data into a data frame and easily output it as a CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
name = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'lists': L})
print(df)

df.to_csv('file.csv', index_label='index')
```

```
    name      lists
0  name1  [1, 2, 3]
1  name2  [4, 5, 6]
2  name3  [7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: When I load the csv and get the list like `df['lists'][0]` , it returns a list like `[1 2 3]` . How can I convert this to a list?

Comment: Pandas is not the ideal tool for storing a list of lists. It looks like it is importing the text as a string.

Comment: You can convert individual columns to a list like this: ``list(pd.eval(df['lists'][0]))``, which gives ``[1, 2, 3]``.

Comment: Turns out I was storing a numpy array and converting it to a list and then using `pd.eval()` on it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the default kwargs for [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) it will recognize that the list has commas in the string representation of the list and automatically quote it for you.

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
   L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
   fieldnames = ['index', 'name', 'lists']
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(fieldnames)
   for i, row in enumerate(L):
       writer.writerow([str(i), 'name{}'.format(i), row])
```

If you look at `filename.csv` you get

```
index,name,lists
0,name_0,"[1, 2, 3]"
1,name_1,"[4, 5, 6]"
2,name_2,"[7, 8, 9]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have 3 rows in your sheet, is that correct? 
If so, Pandas.DataFrame would be a great fit for this issue.

```
#import pandas moudle first
import pandas as pd  


#If you want to add `index` as the column name
index=[0,1,2]
name =['name 0','name 1','name 2']
#This is your original list in Python
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

#Using pd.DataFrame function to reformat the list into table
#Name the first column as 'index', the second column as 'name', and the last column as'lists'

table = pd.DataFrame({'index':index,
                      'name':name,
                      'lists':L})

#Write DataFrame to a comma-separated values (csv) file
table.to_csv('L.csv', index=False)
```

If you try to print the result, it will show like following (apologize I don't know how to embed the table properly)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>index</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>list</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>name 1</td>
    <td>[1, 2, 3]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name 2</td>
    <td>[4, 5, 6]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name 3</td>
    <td>[7, 8, 9]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```